# PHP json_decode() fail on Sun with a depth greater than 6

Tags: php, json

one of my PHP script get JSON from an Ajax call. With a depth of 5, all run fine, but if depth is 6, json_decode() fail on Sun box. Under Linux or Windows same scripts and data run fine.
Does anyone have an hint for me?

Thanks, Cédric

Comment: Can you give an example of data that doesn’t work?

Comment: Which version of php runs on that sun box? Which flavour ? (E.g. "built from php.net vanilla source, no additional patches")

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to tell we have the same problem on Sun with 5.2.0, 5.2.11 and 5.2.12 version of PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to try [jsonwrapper](http://www.boutell.com/scripts/jsonwrapper.html). It is a wrapper implementation of the `json_encode` and `json_decode` functions. They are probably a bit slower than the native implementation, but if it works with your case you can safely say that Sun's native json implementation is broken and you should file a bug.